# Excel pull previous Value per name

Tags: excel

I have the following Table in excel, I'm trying to come up with a calculation for "Prior Time" and "Prior Type" to fill down the table by Day and Name. once I have that I can then calculate the time each "Type" is taking.

The table has multiple dates, so I only want to look at the time in relation to the prior time above the current row based on the name for the same day.

I'm looking for a solution with a formula  ideally
otherwise a SQL solution as another option

| Date | Time | type | name | prior time | prior type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 8/1/2021 | 4:31:22 | x Work | Max |  |  |
| 8/1/2021 | 4:43:42 | x Work | Linda |  |  |
| 8/1/2021 | 5:43:33 | Break | Max | 4:31:22 | x Work |
| 8/1/2021 | 5:45:42 | x Work | John |  |  |
| 8/1/2021 | 5:46:42 | Break | Linda | 4:43:42 | x Work |
| 8/1/2021 | 6:01:12 | x Work | Max | 5:43:33 | Break |
| 8/1/2021 | 7:44:22 | Break | Max | 6:01:12 | x Work |

Comment: Are you trying to do it with VBA or Formulas?

Comment: Formula ideally, 2nd option would be SQL

Answer (score 1):

For the prior time formula use the following formula and format the column to not show the zeros (see screenshot for custom format).

```
=MAXIFS($B$1:B1,$D$1:D1,Sheet3!$D2,$A$1:A1,Sheet3!$A2)
```

For the prior type formula use

```
=IF(G2=0,"",INDEX($C$2:$C$8,MATCH(D2&G2,INDEX($D$2:$D$8&$B$2:$B$8,0),0)))
```

Copy down. See in action in screenshot below.

[image]

Comment: If that resolved your issue, please mark the answer as described in the [tour]. If it didn't, please leave a comment, so I can follow up.

Comment: ok so I was trying something very similar, when I get to row 4, I'm getting 5:43:33. using =MAXIFS($B$2:B4,$D$2:D4,$D4,$A$4:A4,$A4)

Comment: Please, this is not a site for discussions. If you want to chat, you're in the wrong place. If my answer resolved your question, accept it. If you have a better answer, you can post it as an answer. Take the [tour] to learn how this site works.

Answer (score 0):

This works for finding the prior time based on name.

=MAX(IF(D2:D4=D4,IF(ISERROR(MATCH(B2:B4,B4,0)),B2:B4)))